# PHP remove EVERY non alpha-numeric character

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to remove all alpha-numeric characters from a string and replace with a space (using PHP). The input is coming from a textarea that has data pasted into it from various places like word, excel, websites, emails etc.

I was using this regex

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/
```

But I found that there are still `Vertical Tabs` (ascii #13). I want my end result to only include letters and numbers, no newline, tab, vertical tabs etc

Many thanks!

Comment: Vertical tab is space character \s,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vertical tabs are matched by the whitespace character (`\s`)

If you want to replace every non-alpha-numeric character with a space, use

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $string)
```

If you want to replace every group (consecutive characters) of non-alnums with a single space, use

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', ' ', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the \s

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/
```

Answer (score 0):

`\s` is probably used for vertical spaces.

So just remove that:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/
```